# How to assign a Guest Order to a Customer - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I've got some order from guest and later they create their account and ask to link the old orders.

How can I do it?

I tried to update the table sales_order but it wasn't enough to work.

Thanks

Comment: It's Magento 1, but helps http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58465/how-can-i-assign-an-order-to-a-customer

Comment: did you solved this ?

Answer (score 16):

Using SQL

```
UPDATE sales_order SET customer_id = {YOUR CUSTOMER ID}, customer_is_guest = 0 where entity_id = {YOUR ORDER ID};
UPDATE sales_order_grid SET customer_id = {YOUR CUSTOMER ID} where entity_id = {YOUR ORDER ID};
```

Using PHP (if customer exist)

```
public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
) {
    ...
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
}

public function execute()
{
    $incrementId = {YOUR ORDER ID};
    $customerId = {YOUR CUSTOMER ID};

    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('increment_id', $incrementId, 'eq')->create();
    $order = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getFirstItem();

     if ($order->getId() && !$order->getCustomerId()) 
     {
        $order->setCustomerId($customerId);
        $order->setCustomerIsGuest(0);
        $this->orderRepository->save($order);
     ...
```

Using a Module: [Example on my GitHub](https://github.com/magepal/magento2-guest-to-customer).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Renon Stewart answer, in case you have downloadable products in your orders you also need to attach the links to the customer. You can do so with the following SQL queries:

```
UPDATE sales_order SET customer_id = {YOUR CUSTOMER ID}, customer_is_guest = 0 where entity_id = {YOUR ORDER ID};
UPDATE sales_order_grid SET customer_id = {YOUR CUSTOMER ID} where entity_id = {YOUR ORDER ID};
UPDATE downloadable_link_purchased SET customer_id = {YOUR CUSTOMER ID} WHERE order_id = {YOUR ORDER ID};
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but since this is currently the first result in Google I would like to share a more robust way of handling this via PHP.

Magento offers a PHP service class that takes care of this process (`\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CustomerAssignment`)

To utilize this you will need to retrieve the customer and order (eg. using the repositories) and then pass them to this service.

```php
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CustomerAssignment $customerAssignment
) {
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->customerAssignment = $customerAssignment;
}

/**
 * @param int $orderId
 * @param int $customerId
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(int $orderId, int $customerId): void
{
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
    $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);

    $this->customerAssignment->execute($order, $customer);
}
```

Alternatively, you could also retrieve the customer via email by using `$this->customerRepository->get($customerEmail)`

Comment: Hi Martie - this looks to be the best answer if it really is that simple; I just bought an extension from bsscommerce that claims that there are some reasons why their extension can't do this (their explanation is not clear), but maybe they are not aware of this functionality. What version has it been in, do you know?

Comment: Hi @grok_in_full, I’m not sure of the exact version, but according to the Magento 2 github repo the file was added 5 years ago, so this wasn’t originally available when this question was asked (in 2016)

Answer (score 0):

You have to update both tables:

***sales_order***
and
***sales_order_grid***

and change the customer ID from *NULL* to the ID of your customer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $orderId = YOURID;

    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);

    if ($order->getId() && !$order->getCustomerId()) {
        $order->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
        $order->setCustomerIsGuest(0);
        $this->orderRepository->save($order);
    }
```